# Programmatically convert XPS to Excel

Tags: xps

I was trying to adapt xps format files to be recognised by my tool. My tool runs on vba code (excel), so was trying to convert the xps format to excel.

Has anyone given a try to do so? if so pls can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

An XPS file is very similar to a PDF in that it's a representation of a printed page and thus doesn't normally retain any semantic information such as what data constitutes a table and what relation, if any, they have to each other.

I'm not familiar with XPS's internals, but if there is a structure for representing a grid of cells then it should be easy to extract information, but if it's just a bunch of text arranged in a grid then you'll have to devise an algorithm that can detect patterns of regularly-placed text (i.e. a grid layout) and extract the text from there.